# I feel my shock absorbers are no more working. Need to know if I need to replace them or are there any recommendations to ge them properly repaired?

Tags: suspension, bajaj, pulsar

Pulsar 150CC.. Rear shockers. Bajaj showroom Mechanic suggests to replace them but other mechanic suggests that they can be repaired. it ran around 54K. I am confused now. Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

You can repair them, but I doubt it will cost much less than replacing them on your bike. If it were a BMW with big, expensive shocks then maybe it is a good option, but for such a small bike you'll probably pay less for a new shock absorber than for the labour to fix it.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I am not aware of the pricing at all neither repair nor replacement. I will look into that but I am not sure which kind of shock absorbers I need to go with.. What options do I have for my Pulsar 150CC 2010 model.

Comment: I don't really know. I'm in South Africa and the Bajaj brand isn't big here, so I can't find any options or prices for you.